# XML Injection on fortify issue

Tags: c#, xml, security, c#-4.0, fortify

I had below code in my project

```
 XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
 return document.CreateNavigator();
```

fortify displaying the xml injection in the above code. How to solve this xml injection ?

Comment: Seeing as you provided absolutely no context what so ever - i would say this can be easily solved with input validation.

Answer (score 0):

"Extension functions and variables can be useful in prevention of XML injection attacks."

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715.aspx

The main idea in preventing an XPath injection is to pre-compile the XPath expression you want to use and to allow variables (parameters) in it, which during the evaluation process will be substituted by user-entered values

In .NET:

1. Have your XPath expresion pre-compiled with XPathExpression.Compile().
2. Use the XPathExpression.SetContext() Method to specify as context an XsltContext object that resolves some specific variables to the user-entered values.

The source above, basiclly cotains all the  information you need.